# \n displaying in interactive shell

Tags: python, interactive-shell

I'm a newbie scriptwriter and I was testing out my script using the interactive shell `-i`.

This is part of my script:

```
shelp = "min               shows the number of minutes\n\
sec               shows the number of seconds\n\
min + [NUMBER]    adds the number of minutes\n\
sec + [NUMBER]    adds the number of seconds"
```

When I run shelp in interactive, it shows:

```
'min               shows the number of minutes\nsec               shows the number of seconds\nmin + [NUMBER]    adds the number of minutes\nsec + [NUMBER]    adds the number of seconds'
```

I'm not sure if this is what it is supposed to do but is there a way to remove the `\n` while still be able to run my script in interactive?

Sorry if this is had already been answered or if I got my facts wrong

Comment: How do you print your shelp binding? Only print() function convert `\n` character into an endline.

Comment: you could use triple-quotes `"""for multiline strings"""` instead of `\n\` at the end of each line

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for `print()`:

```
>>> print(shelp)
min               shows the number of minutes
sec               shows the number of seconds
min + [NUMBER]    adds the number of minutes
sec + [NUMBER]    adds the number of seconds
>>>
```

The `\n` represents a *newline* and is where the line breaks if you use `print()`. If you just type `shelp` by itself, the interactive shell prints the *representation* of the string, which uses `\n` to show where the line breaks will go.